# Visual Studio Method Parameter Popup Persisting?

Tags: visual-studio

Something that I am finding really irritating about Visual Studio is that when I am typing out a method call, the editor doesn't tell me where my cursor is in the method call in relation to the parameter order. For example, if I am typing a call to a Draw method, and I am on the third parameter, there should be a popup telling me what exactly should go in the third parameter. In my current setup it only tells me the entire method parameters when I click my cursor on the method name in the call. So basically if my cursor is on the third parameter, and I forget what to type here, I have to move my cursor back to the method name part of the call to see what goes there. It sounds minor, but after having to do this so many times it builds up and I am getting tired of it.

Is there some kind of feature in the editor that I can enable to fix this annoying issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for? The current parameter is bold.

You can get this tooltip by Ctrl+Shift+Space.

[image]